# Why can't I take a screenshot for my entire screen witha powershell script?

Tags: powershell, screen-resolution

Can someone help me out with the code below, I found this online.
It works but it only takes a screenshot of a part of the screen. I'm not really sure where to edit either. What I'm trying to do is take a screenshot of the entire screen.

````
$pathfolder=$args[0]
$Name = $args[1]
function Take-Screenshot{
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
 [Drawing.Rectangle]$bounds, 
 [string]$path,
 [string]$Width,
  [string]$Height
) 

   $bmp = New-Object Drawing.Bitmap $bounds.width, $bounds.height
   $graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)
   $graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size)
   $bmp.Save($path)
   $graphics.Dispose()
   $bmp.Dispose()
}
 
function Get-ScreenResolution {
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
  [string]$Width,
  [string]$Height
  
)
 
 $Screens = [system.windows.forms.screen]::AllScreens
 foreach ($Screen in $Screens) {
  $DeviceName = $Screen.DeviceName
  $Width  = $Screen.Bounds.Width
  $Height  = $Screen.Bounds.Height
  $IsPrimary = $Screen.Primary
  $OutputObj = New-Object -TypeName PSobject
  $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DeviceName -Value $DeviceName
  $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Width -Value $Width
  $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Height -Value $Height
  $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IsPrimaryMonitor -Value $IsPrimary
  $OutputObj
 }
}
#Main script begins
 


$ComputerName = $env:computername
$underscore="_"
$datetime = $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss)
$FileName = "$Name$underscore$ComputerName$underscore$datetime"
$Filepath ="$pathfolder\$FileName.png"
 
[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
 
if(!($width -and $height)) {
 
 $screen = Get-ScreenResolution | ? {$_.IsPrimaryMonitor -eq $true}
 $Width = $screen.Width
 $Height = $screen.height
}
 
$bounds = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB(0, 0, $Screen.Width, $Screen.Height)
 
Take-Screenshot -Bounds $bounds -Path $Filepath ```
And I use a batch script to run it 
```powershell -command "C:\take_screenshot.ps1 %1 %2"  ```
````

Comment: The code you've posted already takes a screenshot of the entire screen.

Comment: what are the parameter values you are sending to this script?

Comment: The parameter values I'm sending to this script are the screenname and the path to save it

Comment: it work in my PC and get the entire screen, but when I try to test it into a VM, i take a part of the screen.